# Limit of the normal density function as the variance and the mean approache zero

Tags: probability, limits

$f(v,x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}v}\exp(-\frac{1}{2}(\frac{x}{v}-1)^2), x \ne 0, v >0$

$f(v,x)$ is the density of a normally distributed r.v. with mean $v$ and variance $v^2$.

I need to show that $\lim_{v \to 0}f(v,x)=0$ if $x \ne 0$.

I tried to fight the problem with L'Hôpital's gun, but it became only worth.

$\lim_{v \to 0}f(v,x)=\lim_{v \to 0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-\frac{1}{2}(\frac{x}{v}-1)^2)(\frac{x}{v}-1)\frac{x}{v^2}$

Comment: Yet another example that L'H is vastly overrated. Consider $h(\nu)=(x/\nu-1)^2+2\log\nu$, what is the limit of $h(\nu)$ when $\nu\to0$? This requires to know the limit of $\nu^2\log\nu$, what is it?

Comment: I suggest using the identity $f = e^{ln(f)}$ and analyzing the limit of the log.

Answer (score 0):

It would be enough to show that
$$\lim_{v\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{v}\exp\left(-\left(\frac{x-v}{v}\right)^2\right)=0.$$
Let $u=\frac{x-v}{v}$. (If $v\rightarrow 0$ then $|u|\rightarrow +\infty$.) Also, $\frac{1}{v}=\frac{u+1}{x}$ and we have to show that 
$$\lim_{u\rightarrow \infty}\frac{u+1}{x}e^{(-u^2)}=\frac{1}{x}\lim_{u\rightarrow \infty}\frac{u+1}{e^{u^2}}.$$

Then the good old L'Hospital would say that
$$\frac{1}{x}\lim_{u\rightarrow \infty}\frac{u+1}{e^{u^2}}=\frac{1}{x}\lim_{u\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{2ue^{u^2}}=0.$$
($x\not =0$.)